# Laravel 10 Echo listing event for pusher for real time change?

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, echo, pusher

Here is My web route

```
Route::post('/create/store', [TaskController::class, 'store'])->name('task.store')->middleware('auth');
```

store method in the controller for inserting data

```
public function store()
{
    $validateData = request()->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
    ]);

    $task = new Task;
    $task->title = $validateData['title'];
    $task->description = $validateData['description'];
    $task->username = auth()->user()->name;
    $task->save();
    event(new TaskCreated($task));
    return to_route('task.create')->with('message', 'task successfully added');
}
```

my event class

```
class TaskCreated
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;


    public function __construct(public Task $data)
    {
    }

    public function broadcastOn(): Channel
    {
        return new Channel('task-added');
    }

    public function broadcastAs(): string
    {
        return 'task-event';
    }

}
```

Index Blade File Where I want to listen to the live  changes for insert records

```
<x-layout>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Pusher Data Fetch</h1>
        <div class="container text-center">
            <div class="row row-cols-3 gap-4">
                @foreach($tasks as $task)
                    <x-task-card :task="$task">
                    </x-task-card>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="module">
        console.log("Hello")
        console.log(Echo.channel("task-added"))
        Echo.channel('task-added').listen('.task-event', (e) => {
            console.log(e)
        })
    </script>
</x-layout>
```

***I have used Vite in laravel but the callback is not triggered when inserting the record.
please help me on achieving how I can listen to real-time change events in laravel 10 using Pusher and Echo.***